# getting an exception when running play framework in console

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I have play framework v2.2.1 on Windows which was working previously. However,now when I run "play run" in the console, I'm getting the following error:

```
java lang nosuchmethodexception: play.core.server.NettyServer.maindevhttpmode(play.core.SBTLink, play.core.SBTDocHandler
```

I have SBT v 0.13.1 on my computer.  Any ideas on what might be causing this issue and how it can be fixed barring re-installing or upgrading play framework - I have already tried running play clean and play reload but that has not helped.

JDK version is 1.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused (not sure about root problem as of yet) by the following dependency and I was able to run play run after removing this dependency from my build sbt file:

```
   Resolver.url("Edulify Repository", url("http://edulify.github.io/modules/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

&

```
   "com.edulify" %% "play-hikaricp" % "1.4.1",
```

This dependency was added to add support for hikaricp DB connection pool as a play module.  I might have made a mistake (or not read the requirements clearly enough when adding this module) - will revisit at later stage.